# What does it mean to "trigger" an event in SimPy?

Tags: python, simpy

I am a newbie to SimPy 4.0.2 and discrete-event simulation. I have got quite confused about what it really means to "trigger" an event.

According to the official "Docs » SimPy in 10 Minutes » Basic Concepts", it states that:

> When a process yields an event, the process gets suspended. SimPy resumes the process, when the event occurs (we say that the event is triggered).

This seems to me it means that an event, when triggered, would be popped from the event queue for processing.

Also according to "Docs » Topical Guides » Events", however, it states that:

> If an event gets triggered, it is scheduled at a given time and inserted into SimPy’s event queue.

So this means that an event, when triggered, would be inserted into the event queue?

I am wondering what would really happen regarding the operation on the event queue when an event is triggered? This question is actually also related to other definitions, e.g., "processed", `yield`. Considering the diagram below (if it is not too off), should "triggered" correspond to point A or B? Thank you very much!

```
   inserted?       popped?
  triggered?     triggered?  processed?
      |              |<--event-->|
      V              V           V
    --A--------------B-----------C--> (time)
      ^              ^
      |              |
 yield event    yield event
 (suspended?)    (resumed?)
```

Comment: Did you find any clarification on this?  I find it confusing.  I originally thought that when a process yielded an event, the event was "triggered", but I found out that was not true, so now I don't know what the difference between triggered and processed is.  I also find it odd that the docs say "is going to happen (triggered)" and yet also say "To trigger an event and mark it as failed, call Event.fail(exception)" How can it already be failed (past tense) if it is going to happed (future tense)?

Comment: And in the example [here](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/process_interaction.html#interrupting-another-process), the comment for `if not charging.triggered:` says `# Interrupt charging if not already done.`, which suggests that "triggered" means "done".

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when a event is triggered it gets scheduled to get processed in a event queue.  Most events are scheduled at the time they are triggered.  The one, and only exception I can think of that allows you to schedule its processing in the future is the timeout event.

Techically, when you create a timout event, it is triggered when created and scheduled on the event queue at time (now + delay) for processing.

So when most events get triggered at time t, they are also scheduled to be processed at time t, and processed at time t.

Also note that the simulation is single threaded so then event queue also sorts all the events scheduled to be processed at the same time by fifo and the events are processed one at a time.

When you yield to a event, you are waiting for that event to finish being processed, even if that event has not yet been triggered and scheduled on the event queue.